# Do linear transformations need to be injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I've recently been studying linear algebra and I'm beginning to wonder if one way to tell if a function is a linear transformation is whether it's injective, or, in other words, to test the truth value of the claim "if a function is a linear transformation, then it is injective."

To be clear, I will state a rough definition of linear transformations:

> A linear transformation is a function $f:X \to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces, satisfying the following:

> For all vectors $\hat{x},\hat{y} \in X, $ $f(\hat{x}+\hat{y})=f(\hat{x})+f(\hat{y})$

> For all scalars $c$, $f(c \cdot \hat{x})=c \cdot f(\hat{x})$

One thing I'm noticing is that it would appear that all of the functions I can imagine that fail to satisfy these conditions are not injective.

**Non-Injective:**

$ \bullet \, \sin(x+y)\neq \sin(x)+ \sin(y) \hspace{1cm} \sin(cx) \neq c \cdot \sin(x)$

$\bullet \, |x+y| \neq |x|+|y| \hspace{1cm} |cx| \neq c \cdot|x|$

Now consider the functions that *do* satisfy the definition:

**Injective:**

$\bullet$ Any line passing through the origin: $\, f(x)=a \cdot x; \, a(x+y)=a \cdot x + a \cdot y$ and $a \cdot (cx) = c (a \cdot x)$

---

I suppose that injectivity often helps for linear transformations, but I would imagine that it is not a necessity. For example, the function $f(x)=x^3$ is injective but surely $(x+y)^3 \neq x^3 + y^3$

It would appear I've answered my own question in that "linear transformations need not be injective," but is there a proof of the notion that "all non-injective functions fail to be linear transformations?"

Comment: Projections are linear transformations.

Comment: More precisely, consider the projection of a 2D vector on the $x$-axis: $(x,y)\mapsto(x,0)$. This is linear but not injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a slightly more interesting non-injective linear transformation: Take $C^1(\mathbb{R})$, the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of continuously differentiable functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, and $C^0(\mathbb{R})$, the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Let
$$
D : C^1(\mathbb{R}) \to C^0(\mathbb{R}), \quad f \mapsto f'.
$$
This defines a linear transformation. However, you can check that
$$
\ker(D) = \bigcup_{a \in \mathbb{R}}\{f_a\} \subset C^1(\mathbb{R}),
$$
where $f_a : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto a$. So in particular, $\ker(D) \neq \{0\}$, hence $D$ is not injective. Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 13):

The most basic example of a non-injective linear map is $z : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $z(x) = 0$.

The theory of when a linear map is injective is studied extensively in linear algebra. There are many theorems about when such a map is injective when the vector spaces are finite-dimensional.